Как сделать, чтобы объект не выходил за границы объекта типа стены
Делаю игру "Арканоид" на SFML. Я решил сделать так, чтобы мячик не выходил за границы не просто самого окна, а моего спрайта в виде стен с потолком. Подскажите, пожалуйста, идею, как это можно реализовать.

Использовать какой-нибудь физический фреймворк

a если без фреймворка?
